# Run Performane Test on deployment server through TeamCity and Octopus deploy

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity, integration-testing, continuous-deployment, octopus

Hi We are using TeamCity and OCtopus for CI/CD. We have several hundred test cases. 
As set up we have build server (Machine A) and it gets deployed on server (Machine B)

We use TeamCity and and last step is Deploy step through OctopusDeploy.

We have several test case which gets executed as Pre Deploy Tests. **Now I want to add few Performance test case which will run on server (Machine B)**. How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Octopus` is already helping us with this , You can write a `PowerShell` step that can run your performane testing cases. So the actual process of performing the tests is pretty easy.Moreover if you wanna check the test results with display (viewing the test results) .In Octopus 2.0 you can “attach” files to a deployment via PowerShell which are then uploaded and available on the deployment page.

But there is a possibility where you can run the load tests from the Teamcity using TC `JMeter plugin` and you can Parameterise the target environment and run the load tests , Here below is the link which can help you.

https://devblog.xero.com/run-jmeter-performance-tests-on-teamcity-8315f7ccffc1

References and sources:

https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts